# SQL - calculate MODE without sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate the MODE of a single column in SQL. This is done easily enough with:

```
SELECT v AS Mode  
FROM Data  
GROUP BY v HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data GROUP BY v);
```

However, I would like to do this *without sorting*, i.e. without using `GROUP BY` or any similar construct. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: may be best to provide sample data. cheers.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn the data would be pretty simple - just a list of integers for instance (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 11, 8, 20, 1)

Answer (score 1):

`group by` doesn't do sorting.  It does partitioning.  So instead of 1 aggregate result, you get 1 result per group in which all values that you `group by` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL the best I could come up with is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00293c/2):

```
select distinct v from(
select v,
@cnt := (select count(*) from Data d1 where d1.v=d.v) as cnt_,
case when @cnt>=@max then @max:=@cnt end as max_
from Data d,
(select @max:=1, @cnt:=1) c) a
where cnt_ = @max
```

For SQL Server, Oracle or Postgres you can use a window function:

```
with a as (
v, select row_count() OVER(PARTITION BY v) rn
from Data
)
select v as Mode
FROM a
where rn = (select max(rn) from a)
```

Comment: Isn't that last `order by` a form of sorting, though?

Comment: I can't make everyone happy, sorry

Comment: How about this? - no order by

Comment: I can't seem to get this to run in my environment. Guessing it's because this solution doesn't work for MySQL? I need something that is supported by MySQL.

Comment: Modify your question and use the correct [MySQL] tag